# Jquery ToolTip not working

Tags: jquery-plugins

I am using jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js.

I have a hyperlink on the page and am trying to do the following but doesn't seem to work.

```
     $('a').tooltip({

        content: function () {
            return 'This is a test';
         } 
      });
```

Nothing shows up. What am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Tooltip](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/) widget was introduced in [jQuery UI 1.9.0](http://blog.jqueryui.com/2012/10/jquery-ui-1-9-0/).

You have to upgrade to this release in order to use it.